# Compute value of moving window in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a CSV with data that has numeric values in multiple columns. My goal is to add a column to the end that has a -1, 0 or 1 based on whether the next 5 values in a specific column go below/above the original column.

For example, the data below, the `np.where` I can do a single if start > end in the same column but how can I look ahead? I want to have a move column where if the start value is the lowest of the next 5 end values, put a 1. If the start is the highest of the next 5, put a -1. If the end values go above and below, then return a 0.

```
start   end    move
0       5      1   // the start value here is the lowest of the next 5     end values
5       10     1   // same as above
10      15     1   // same as above
15      25     1   // same as above
25      30     1   // same as above
30      35     0   // end goes up and down so 0 here
35      40     0   // same as above
40      30    -1   // next are all below 40 so -1 now 
30      20
20      15
15      10    
10      5
```

Comment: If using `np.where`, you should be showing the loaded array, not the `csv`.And show the code that uses `where`.

Comment: Looks like this is a job for pandas. Stride tricks will work too.

Comment: I would start with a function that works for one row.  And then apply it row by row.  Unless the real case is very large, or this task is done repeatedly it probably isn't worth doing something complicated or esoteric.

Comment: When doing rolling window operations like this, use stride tricks. The more you can get numpy to do for you under the hood, the happier you'll be.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed your title. This has nothing to do with np.where.

Comment: The original loop compared the start and end values in the same row so that is where I started it. Wasn't sure if there was a way to build onto the np.where() logic of take another path.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [142]: txt = """0       5      1   // the start value here is the lowest of
     ...:  the next 5     end values
     ...: 5       10     1   // same as above
     ...: 10      15     1   // same as above
     ...: 15      25     1   // same as above
     ...: 25      30     1   // same as above
     ...: 30      35     0   // end goes up and down so 0 here
     ...: 35      40     0   // same as above
     ...: 40      30    -1   // next are all below 40 so -1 now 
     ...: 30      20
     ...: 20      15
     ...: 15      10    
     ...: 10      5"""
In [143]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), usecols=[0,1],encoding=None, 
     ...: dtype=int)
In [144]: data
Out[144]: 
array([[ 0,  5],
       [ 5, 10],
       [10, 15],
       [15, 25],
       [25, 30],
       [30, 35],
       [35, 40],
       [40, 30],
       [30, 20],
       [20, 15],
       [15, 10],
       [10,  5]])
```

Write a function to handle one row (and the next 5):

```
In [145]: def foo(data,i):
     ...:     start = data[i,0]
     ...:     ends = data[i:i+5,1]
     ...:     if (start<ends).all():
     ...:         return 1
     ...:     if (start>ends).all():
     ...:         return -1
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return 0
     ...:
```

test for specific `i` - surprise, I got it right the first time!  Often interpreting word descriptions is tricky and subject to ambiguities.

```
In [146]: foo(data,0)
Out[146]: 1
In [147]: foo(data,5)
Out[147]: 0
In [148]: foo(data,7)
Out[148]: -1
```

Now just iterate to get a list:

```
In [149]: [foo(data,i) for i in range(8)]
Out[149]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
```

Padding this list so it can be appended to `data` is left as an exercise for the reader (or OP).

Comment: I figured out a way without loops :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using numpy, you can do a trick using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). If we add an extra dimension of size 5 to our array such that the stride in that dimension takes you to the next element, you can just take the minimum and maximum along the extra dimension and compare to the original array.

Keeping in mind that `as_strided` is a loaded cannon that would shoot you in the foot as soon as do anything else:

```
start = np.array([0,5,10,15,25,30,35,40,30,20,15,10])
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(start, shape=(start.size - 4, 5), strides=start.strides * 2, writeable=False)
move = ((start[:-4] == view.min(axis=1)).astype(int) - (start[:-4] == view.max(axis=1)))
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/p4ef7G)